# Flutter release update bundle with reduced size (Only modifications/updates)

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have recently upload my flutter android app(~20 MB) bundle to google playstore. After few days, i made some minor correction/bugs and update the app bundle. Once it is published, in playstore, shows update with full app size(~20 MB). Every time i update, it happens the same. Is there any way to reduce the update size since it is only very small changes.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the APK? `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Comment: I'm not building apk. I build bundle .abb to upload playstore. The thing i need is, can i build the app bundle only for the new changes/corrections to reduce the update size in playstore.